# FBLoginDialog auto ask for Basic Permission before didLogin

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am using the old facebook iphone sdk to develop a iphone app: https://github.com/megastep/facebook-iphone-sdk

I am currently encountering a problem: The FBLoginDialog auto ask for Basic Permission before the didLogin callback.

I want to skip this part as I want to ask Exteneded permission.

And idea why facebook is asking the basic permission before the callback didLogin?

Thanks.

```
    FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:session] autorelease];  
    // dialog.delegate = self;
    [dialog show];
```

Comment: a tipp for free, use the new sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move to the new SDK.  The SDK you are using is known to be buggy in several ways, it leaks memory and has problems on the 4.2 OS when the user is editing text and the keyboard is on screen.

Note also that the new SDK makes it extremely easy to ask for whatever permissions you need, you can just do it in the authorize:delegate method (see the sample project included in the sdk for an example).

Edit/Update:

Facebook asks for basic auth before didLogin because the user has to at least authorize your application.